# Bash run command with cd to each directory

Tags: python, bash, shell, ipython

I have command that I cannot specify the output destination so the output files are saved in the directory that the bash script is run.

```
find | xargs ipython nbconvert
```

This saves all the converted files from each subdirectories into the directory that the command gets run. I want to output the converted files onto each file's present directory.

Then how do I specify the destination of a command that has no option for output directory?

I want to run something like

```
 find | convert .
```

So that each file gets saved in its directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find | xargs` is a bad idea anyway, as filenames with spaces or other unusual characters can confuse the issue. Fortunately `find` comes with a flag called `-execdir` which pretty much does exactly what you want.

```
find -execdir ipython nbconvert {} \;
```

Have a look at the [find manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html) for the details.

---

As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out in the comments, not all versions of `find` support the `-execdir` feature. For those that don't, you can take advantage of the fact that the output is on individual lines and create a while loop to iterate through each result, applying a `cd` before running your program.

```
find | while read line; do
  cd "$(dirname "$line")"
  ipython nbconvert "$line"
done
```

You can also achieve this within python itself, if you'd prefer it always run in the directory of its first argument. If you're using `sys.argv` instead of one of the more advanced option parsers, you could add something like this to the beginning of your python script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import os.path
    import sys
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]))
```

You could also specify an explicit path for your output file when you `open` it, such as

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]), 'name_of_output_file.txt') as fb:
    pass # your code here
```

Comment: `-execdir` is not part of the POSIX standard, so some versions of `find` may not support it. GNU `find` and the version that ships with Mac OS X (and all BSDs?) do, however.